# Providing dashboard and reporting capabilities with MVC 4

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jqgrid, reporting

I'm currently thinking about implementing a reporting solution at work using Asp.net MVC 3 or 4. This version we're looking to implement a simple dashboard and some simple grids that provide sorting, filtering, paging etc... The options I've explored so far are: on the client side using  JQGrid, JQPlot or buying a 3rd party suite of controls like Telerik or DevExpress.  Money is not really a problem.  We're willing to pay for controls if we have to.  My questions is, what are the benefits / disadvantages of each choice (JQuery vs MVC controls)?  What should I be thinking about as far as making a decision?

Thanks

Comment: we are using jqgrid with lib.web.mvc nuget package but still looking for a nice reporting html helpers or package. have you settled on anything yet?

Answer (score 3):

"MVC Controls" don't really exist, anything that is like `@Html.EditorFor()` is just an Html Helper that will write simple html for you.  MVC is meant to completely decouple javascript from the Asp.Net and is actually intended to be used with jQuery (projects start with jQuery references already in them).

Personally, I would stick to jQuery/jQueryUI and possibly some plug-ins. They are widely supported and open source, so you can customize them if you want, unlike proprietary stuff that may not allow that.

Comment: Yeah I meant the MVC extensions.  Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Also consider involving Javascript MVVM framework like Knockout.js etc.